# How to create "infinity" world using OpenGL

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I need to create GameOfLife using OpenGL, and i have one problem. The whole world in this simulation is 100x100 cells, but left and right edge must be connected and top/bottom as well. The problem is how do i show it using camera, because when the right edge is in the middle of the window, i am only looking at right part of the world, but i should look at left part as well.

The specifications of the task are: OpenGL 1.1 with C++, WinApi and glOrtho

Comment: what have you tried? (sounds like home work). if you try to learn opengl and this is some kind of tutorial, you should stop and continue with another tutorial, Immediate mode is deprecated, so you should not even use this as a start point for learning.

Comment: Yeah it's my home work, I know that i shouldn't learn so outdated technology, but what can i do if it's my subject...

Comment: you for sure can ask for help even if it is homework, but you should show something you already did, and where you have problems. otherwise it is unlikely that you would get help.

Comment: I dont want directly help, i just want a hint, maybe some function, rest i can findout myself. And my teacher is not kind of helping person...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a shader that translates coordinates outside your world to inside. Since you're using an orthogonal projection that should be fairly easy to accomplish using modulo calculations in the fragment shader.

Comment: Hmm i guess it would be easy way, but i cant use shaders in this program( sry i didnt tell it earlier ), i should use only basic without any extends. Maybe it will be important, but my camera can move only about size of one cell at once.

Comment: @user2176624: That makes it sound like homework given to you by some teacher or professor. If so, please tell your teacher/professor/TA that the fixed function pipeline of OpenGL has been deprecated for some 10 years now, modern OpenGL works with shaders only and that employers in the field of computer graphics expect solid understanding of shader programming and that the fixed function pipeline is only of historic interest now. So you're not supposed to use extensions and a basic, "core" profile? Well then I suggest you OpenGL-3 core profile: There's no fixed function, you must use shaders.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the world is only 100x100, and I assume that killer graphics aren't a priority (colored squares?), it shouldn't be too hard to just render the scene two times, correct? For example, in the case that the camera is only looking at the right edge, only draw the right-most squares of the scene, and then draw the left-most squares of that screen immediately to the right of the edge of the screen. Then, when the camera extends past the grid boundary, subtract (or, if you're going to the left, add) the camera's x value by 100. It'll be seamless, and you'll have the effect you want--unless I'm missing something, in which case tell me.

Another option would be to render the game of life to a texture, and render that texture (set it to repeat along both axes) to the screen. This would probably be an easier and faster option. Just write rgb data to a buffer (byte array, 3*3*100*100 in length) and map that byte array to a texture. You'll probably find a ton of tutorials on how to do that--including a nehe.gamedev.com legacy tutorial on it (Btw, Nehe is a wonderful resource).

If you choose the texture approach, you don't need any camera math either. Just change the coordinates of the texture mapped on the quad, and it'll wrap automatically.